# Mocking Reflux.js store during React component shallow rendering in test with enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme, refluxjs

I'm writing React application. I want to test in isolation component that is wired up with Reflux.js store with:

```
  mixins: [
    Reflux.connect(CountriesStore)
  ],
```

Initialization code of `CountresStore` calls `action` that tries to fetch list of countries. This is the stop where some exception is being raised. But I feel that all this fuzz should not occur. I want to conduct unit, not integration testing. So,

**Is there a way to mock this `CountriesStore` prior of it being called during initialization of component?**